# Lebesgue integral of difference function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm working on the following problem: Given $f$ integrable over $\mathbb{R}$ with $f$ absolutely continuous and $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|h|}=0$$ Then $f$ is constant.

I know I want to use the fact that since $f$ is absolutely continuous I can write $f$ as an indefinite integral. I also know the result would then follow if I can show that $f'(x)=0$, but I'm having trouble working with the integral to show my derivative is zero.

Comment: What you really want to do is to switch the integral with the limit. Do you know any theorems that would let you do that?

Comment: @bitesizebo I was considering use dominated convergence in some way, but I'm not sure how to set that up here.

Comment: I guess that the lower limit is $-\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea.** The claim will follow if one can show that

$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\right| \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{h \to 0} \left| \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\right| \, \mathrm{d}x, $$

since Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem tells that $\lim_{h \to 0} \left| \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}\right| = \left| f'(x) \right|$ for a.e. $x$. We will indeed show a version of this claim to solve the problem.

---

**Proof.** Perhaps this problem is easily solved by invoking the following variant of Dominated Convergence Theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $f_n, g_n, g \in L^1(\mu)$ satisfy the following conditions:
>
> 1. $|f_n| \leq g_n$ for all $n \geq 1$,
> 2. $f_n$ converges pointwise $\mu$-a.e., and $g_n \to g$  pointwise $\mu$-a.e.
> 3. $\int g_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu \to \int g \, \mathrm{d}\mu $
>
> Then
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \int f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu = \int \lim_{n\to\infty}  f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu. $$

As in the case of the original DCT, it is proved in a routine way, i.e., by invoking Fatou's Lemma. The proof is included at the end of this answer.

Returning to the problem, for any $h > 0$ and $x$, we have

$$ \left| \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \right| = \left| \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h} f'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right| \leq \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h} \left| f'(t) \right| \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

Moreover, Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem tells that $ \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h} \left| f'(t) \right| \, \mathrm{d}t \to |f'(x)|$ for a.e. $x$ and Fubini-Tonelli Theorem tells that

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h} \left| f'(t) \right| \, \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{h} \int_{t-h}^{t} \left| f'(t) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}t
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| f'(t) \right| \, \mathrm{d}t.
\end{align*}

So, if $(h_n)$ is any sequence of positive real numbers converging to $0$, then the above theorem and Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem together show that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| \frac{f(x+h_n) - f(x)}{h_n}\right| \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} \left| \frac{f(x+h_n) - f(x)}{h_n}\right| \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left| f'(x) \right| \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Now the assumption tells that this is zero, and so, $f' = 0$ a.e. and the desired conclusion follows. $\square$

---

**Addendum - Proof of Theorem.** Write $f = \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n$. Then Fatou's lemma tells that

\begin{align*}
\int (g - f) \, \mathrm{d}\mu
&= \int \liminf_{n\to\infty} (g_n - f_n) \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int (g_n - f_n) \, \mathrm{d}\mu \\
&= \int g \, \mathrm{d}\mu - \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\end{align*}

and similarly

\begin{align*}
\int (g + f) \, \mathrm{d}\mu
&= \int \liminf_{n\to\infty} (g_n + f_n) \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int (g_n + f_n) \, \mathrm{d}\mu \\
&= \int g \, \mathrm{d}\mu + \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu.
\end{align*}

Therefore we have

$$ \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int f_n \, \mathrm{d}\mu
\leq \int f \, \mathrm{d}\mu, $$

proving the desired claim. $\square$